# Highlight searches in Vim but not substitutions?

Tags: vim

I know it's possible to stop Vim from highlighting on any search, but is there a way to make it highlight on regular searches but not, for instance, substitutions?

I will often highlight a block of text then do something like:

```
:s/^/#/
```

to comment out the whole block. But then I have an ugly yellow bar running up and down the left side of my screen and I have to `:noh` every time to clear it.

I want highlighting to remain on regular /searches. Is this possible?

Comment: Not sure if anything like this will work, but maybe it would be possible to change your 'search' highlight group to look like normal text, and then remap the '/' search key somehow to `:match NewSearchGroup /searchterm/. I'd love to also hear a better way though.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question BUT you should really use [tComment](https://github.com/tomtom/tcomment_vim) (or a similar commenting plugin) for commenting out text blocks. You'll be able to use motions for commenting and can easily comment anything, including XML.

Comment: Maybe you can use [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13636203/778118) to get pointed in the right direction...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This doesn't answer your question fully but for me having the same problem it helped: I added this command to easily deactivate the highlighting after a search or a search-and-replace

```
nnoremap <esc> :noh<return><esc>
```

(from [Vim clear last search highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657447/vim-clear-last-search-highlighting))

Comment: You beat me to it... I was going to recommend mapping the `ENTER` key.

Answer (score 3):

My solution:  put this in your vimrc file

```
set nohlsearch

noremap * :set hlsearch<CR>:nohlsearch<CR>*
noremap / :set hlsearch<CR>:nohlsearch<CR>/
noremap ? :set hlsearch<CR>:nohlsearch<CR>?

nnoremap <F4> :set invhlsearch<CR>
inoremap <F4> <ESC>:set invhlsearch<CR>gi
nnoremap <CR> :set nohlsearch<CR>
```

What it does:

1. Searches always enable highlights.
2. Use <kbd>Enter</kbd> to turn off highlights until the next search, but not the next substitute.  Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> again will not turn them back on though.
3. Use <kbd>F4</kbd> to turn off highlights until the next search, but not next substitute.  Pressing <kbd>F4</kbd> again will toggle the highlights for the last search pattern --- search OR substitute --- if there was one.

**Some notes on highlights that are never really explained well:**
When the `'hlsearch'` option is on, all future searches/substitutes will turn on `"highlight visibility"`.  The current `"highlight visibility"` is not really an option you can directly query or set independently, but you can independently turn OFF highlight visibility with the command `:nohlsearch` (this is not the same as `:set nohlsearch`, because the next search will enable visibility again).

In addition, whenever you run the command `:set hlsearch` there are two effects:  It sets the option AND it makes vim forget if you've ever typed `:nohlsearch`.  In other words, changing `'hlsearch'` (either on or off) will force the current `"highlight visibility"` to logically match.

Comment: Thanks @Ein! Your notes about `:set hlsearch` [helped me figure out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657447/vim-clear-last-search-highlighting) how to get rid of highlighting during a mapping and reenable it without any side effects like match flickering or error messages.